"Man cannot live by bread alone." — Is there any logical explanation why this idiom doesn't have an article before "man"?
cambridge.org:

(1) Man cannot live by bread alone. — (idiom) (saying) (used to say that people need not just food, but also art, music, literature, ideas, etc. to live happily)

Is there any logical explanation why this idiom doesn't have an article before the noun "man"?
my variants:
(2) The man cannot live by bread alone.
(3) Men cannot live by bread alone.
As far as I understand, (2) and (3) are correct.

Search for generic singular.

Man (without any article) and mankind used to be used to refer to human beings in general; hence the word people in the Cambridge definition. In recent years this usage has fallen out of favour (as supposedly implying that women don't count).
The phrase actually comes from Matthew 4:4 in the King James Bible. Some more recent translations say people or humans.

How does your answer relate to the original questions?

@Loviii When man means mankind, the article is not used.

I have edited to clarify.

There's also humankind.

your link has 32 translations and only 1 renders it as "people", so I wouldn't agree with the statement that "more modern translations say people".

@Astralbee - I meant 'translations that are more modern than the KJV', not that 'people' was the most common!

Another famous example of this sense is Darwin’s title, The Descent of Man.

@KateBunting Most English translations are more modern than the KJV. But only 1 out of 32 on your link says 'people' so I'm still wondering why you say 'some'? Even though the original language does use the gender-neutral 'person', it doesn't seem to be the obvious choice for translators. Perhaps that's because we sometimes use 'people' pejoratively, to mean the 'masses'? I don't know, but 'man' or 'mankind' doesn't leave any doubt that it refers to all human beings.

@Astralbee it's not really 32 translations since some are different editions of the same translation. (The choice of what they included is a bit odd IMO.) A second translation in the list uses "people" for the second half of the verse, and a third uses "a person". The Common English Version and World English Bible also use "people", and the New Century Version and International Children's Bible use "a person".

But admittedly it would be more accurate to say "some modern versions use an explicitly gender-neutral term such as..."

@EspeciallyLime Fair comment :) However, I feel all this talk of alternative renderings is a bit moot when the question is whether the given quotation is missing an article or not. Changing a non-count noun to a plural noun may convey the same meaning but it doesn't answer the question. And I think that saying "more modern translations" render it differently sends the message that the original quotation is wrong, or archaic, of which it is neither.

@KateBunting. I am looking for other examples, and mostly the seem to be archaic, e.g. "Man born of Woman hath bit a short time to live...", except for Armstrong trying to sound solemn. I wonder whether this isn't an obsolete form that has fossilized because "everybody" knows the KJV and the Service for the Burial of the Dead? My advice to the OP would be to read the answers, but probably avoid using this construct: by all means read archaic English, but don't create more.

@Astralbee Very true, there are plenty of modern translations which stick to "man shall not", and where others render it differently the reason appears to be (explicit) gender neutrality rather than grammar.

@Astralbee - There's not beyond the wit of man, which is mock-archaic. Actually I said that modern versions use 'people OR humans' - in fact, the variants are people, a person, no-one, human beings and three instances of one.

@EspeciallyLime Or just that they're better translations which reflect what was actually originally said, perhaps. Man, now, does not mean what man meant then. Connotations are an important part of the meaning of a word.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I fully agree that a gender-neutral term better reflects the original meaning. I just meant that is not relevant to OP's actual question, which is about grammar rather than accuracy.

"One small step for [a] man, one giant leap for mankind". (Armstrong claims that he included the indefinite article, but it was inaudible on earth, and is usually omitted from the quote.)


Man cannot live by bread alone.

The OP asks if man can be changed:

The man cannot live by bread alone.
Men cannot live by bread alone.

The question is understandable and reasonable, because there are other contexts in which a noun plus definite article is used to describe that item in general.

In the last fifty years the computer has changed the world.
In the last fifty years computers have changed the world.

These two sentences are both OK and they both mean the same thing.
(Note that the computer can also refer to a single particular object: The computer in my home office is old and needs to be replaced. Whether the noun has a general or particular reference can only be determined by context.)
So with these notes in mind, let's return to the original sentence. I would say that the proposed changes are not suitable here, and it's because of the special background to this particular sentence.
As noted, man cannot live by bread alone has a history. It is a sentence from the Bible:

Matthew 4:3-4 (KJV)
3 And when the tempter came to him, he said, If thou be the Son of God, command that these stones be made bread.
4 But he answered and said, It is written, Man shall not live by bread alone, but by every word that proceedeth out of the mouth of God.

You will notice that the language overall feels old fashioned because of course it is. It is the language of Shakespeare, the language of the sixteenth century. But because this sentence is from the Bible, and even more so because it is a well known story from the life of Jesus, it has taken on a proverbial element. We can see that from the interpretation in the OP. There the saying is applied to social themes such as art or music; in the Bible it is applied specifically to the spiritual food that we receive from God's word.
So can you change it? Technically yes, but you need to understand that you are changing a proverb, not just a sentence. When I read this...

The man cannot live by bread alone

...I immediately think of this...

Man cannot live by bread alone

...and I think that the writer must mean something different, because he is intentionally changing a well known saying.
This is why modern translations either retain the proverbial flavour of the King James Version (see the New International Version [NIV]) or create a completely new style of gender neutral translation (see for example the New Living Translation [NLT]).

+1 Thank you for the detail explanation.


The man hunted, gathered wild berries, and fended for himself.
This refers to a nameless male individual.

So God created man in his own image, […] male and female created he them.
King James Version (1611), Genesis 1:27-29


In this excerpt from the Bible, man represents humanity, both men and women.
In more recent revisions, the term man has either been replaced by mankind or humankind

So God created mankind in his own image,
   in the image of God he created them;
   male and female he created them.
New International Version (1973)


So God created humankind in his image,
    in the image of God he created them;
    male and female he created them.
New Revised Standard Version Catholic Edition 1989 (NRSVCE)

Note the absence of the definite article in these more recent versions. In English it is rare to speak or hear about the mankind or the humankind– I'm sure there are exceptions–but generally speaking, we don't use any article.
Mankind or the mankind?

As Ford Madox Ford might have said to Józef Teodor Konrad Korzeniowski, you mean "unnamed" not "nameless".

@TimR Not the foggiest idea who those men are, but I checked with M-W and nameless seems acceptable 4. not having been given a name : UNNAMED Do I have to change it to "unnamed" if I don't want to risk getting a downvote? Oh, Joseph Conrad!

This is accurate and answers the question: man represents humanity, It is used as a kind of collective noun. I don't understand why people go on and on about questions like these.

Ford was explaining to fellow novelist and friend Conrad the nuanced difference between "penniless" and "without a penny".

"The humankind" is a specific instance of humankind, implying more than one such instance to choose between.

@Mari-LouA nameless and unnamed can both mean "without having a name", but unnamed can also mean "without being named" i.e. without one's name being mentioned.

From your answer I drew the following conclusion: if in "The man hunted, gathered wild berries, and fended for himself", "the man" refers to all males in general, then in "The man cannot live by bread alone", "the man" also refers to all males in general. Am I right? Thanks.

@Loviii Unfortunately not. The man is a specific man. Man cannot live by bread alone. is the only way to say this aphorism. Her first two examples give this properly. However, don't confuse that with: The lion is a noble beast. [countable, takes the for a formal generality.]

@Lambie As far as I understood, Mari-Lou A said that in "The man hunted, gathered wild berries, and fended for himself", "the man" refers to all males in general. Do you agree with this?

@Loviii No it doesn't, "The man" is singular, I said as much in my answer, and in the quote it says: and fended for himself

@Loviii See? I told you. Read what I wrote again please. It is not a generality. man is humanity. She said that too.

@Loviii note also the plural pronoun them which I emphasised in the different Bible passage I quoted: man/mankind/humankind [...] male and female […] them

The quote comes from the Bible, specifically the section of the Bible commonly known as the 'New Testament' which was mainly written in ancient Greek and subsequently translated into modern languages. Although you are asking about the grammar of the English translation, I think it is worth considering the original language as a little aside because it is a good example of how other languages use articles differently to English before we see why the English translation does not require one.
The Greek word translated as "man" is actually ánthropos, which literally translates as person. It's the root word from which we get modern words such as anthropology, the study of human society and culture.
Ancient Greek had a definite article (equivalent to English 'the'), but not an indefinite article. The absence of an indefinite article in the language meant the definite article was used more frequently than we would in English, and for different reasons. For example, in English, we know that "a man" is any particular man, "the man" would be a specific man, and "man" without an article is the generic man, or all mankind. In this text, from Matthew 4:4, the original language uses a definite article and effectively says "the person", but this does not mean a specific person like it would in modern English - it is there to indicate that this is not a single man, like "a man" would indicate.
Translation is about conveying the overall meaning rather than making a word-for-word translation. The correct rendering is therefore any word that expresses the generic man or mankind. There is no need for an article in the English translation for these words as they are generic, uncountable nouns. Plural nouns like people or humans convey the same meaning but in a way that is not as close to the original language.

Good points, +1. It's perhaps worth noting that although this quote appears in the new testament, it is being quoted directly from the old testament (where it's in Hebrew). Presumably similar considerations apply in that language. To add to the confusion, the new testament verse is reporting words spoken by Jesus, presumably in Aramaic.

@EspeciallyLime Two points to address and little space! Firstly, yes - Jesus was quoting existing Hebrew scripture, and it is assumed that Jesus mainly spoke his native language of either Aramaic or a heavily Aramaicised dialect of Hebrew, because Jesus mainly spoke to fellow Jews as per his commission to preach to the "lost sheep of the house of Israel". However, the conversation at Matthew 4 was not with a Jew but with Satan, and nobody else present. It may not have taken place out loud, in any language. The gospel writer, writing in Greek, didn't translate what they heard spoken.

@EspeciallyLime Secondly - Hebrew shares the lack of an indefinite article with Greek (and most ancient languages - I think only ancient Egyptian had an indefinite article?) so I didn't mention this as I'd be explaining the same thing twice. The Hebrew scripture from which Jesus quoted (Deuteronomy 8:3) uses the word hā·’ā·ḏām, which directly translates as the man. Adam means man, and just like my explanation for Greek, when used without an article it is "a man" singular; when used with an article it usually means mankind. So the Greek translation doesn't change it.

many thanks for the extra information! I figured it was likely to be the same issue in all three languages, but I didn't know enough to be sure.

Certainly not "the man", because it applies to all mankind. (3) is almost true to the intent, but limits the subject to "men", whereas it likely was understood that "man" meant "mankind".
English has become more concerned with gender equality in recent years (e.g., "actress" and "comedienne" are no longer P.C.). However, as Neil Armstrong said, "That's one small step for man, one giant leap for mankind." He thought he had said, "That's one small step for a man..."

You wrote: "Certainly not "the man", because it applies to all mankind." — unfortunately I didn't understand this explanation. "The man cannot live by bread alone" seems correct to me because "the man" here refers to all people in general (in other words, to all mankind, as you said). Therefore, "the man" is correct here. Just as "the lion" in "The lion lives in Africa and eats meat" refers to all lions in general. So tell me please where I'm mistaken?

"The man" does not refer to "mankind" or to "all people in general".

@TimR Why does "the man" not refer to all people in general, whereas "the lion" does refer to all lions in general? Thanks.

@Lovii: Why?  Why does the lion eat meat?

"It's just the way we say it." The only explanation I can think of is that using 'the lion' to refer to the species in general is a scientific convention, and (comparatively) recent; using 'man' to refer to humankind in general is much older.

@TimR - why does the bear go to the bathroom in the woods?

@KateBunting Well, as long as you consider medieval bestiaries scientific and comparatively recent:  Whanne þe leoun..is sike..he dredeþ swiþe þe crowynge and þe combe of a cok.  When the lion is sick he very much dreads the crowing and the comb of a cock.

@MichaelHarvey Because he lives in North America?

@TimR - Ok - can you think of a better explanation?

I thought it has been determined that Armstrong did say "step for a man" but it wasn't (easily) audible for technical reasons.

@KateBunting  I don't have an explanation  why "the man" cannot refer to homo sapiens but "the Frenchman" can refer generically to the class "French citizen".  In that regard, all we can do, I think, is describe what flies and what doesn't.

As far as I understood your answer, you say "men" in "Men cannot live by bread alone" means not "people", but "males". But a dictionary says "men" can mean "people". For example: "He believes that all men are created equal". Then why can't "men" in "Men cannot live by bread alone" mean "people" as it does in the dictionary's example? Thanks.

@Loviii Believe it or not, for thousands of years women were not viewed as being equal to men…

It's a pity that we no longer use were-man for specifically male people, freeing "man" for inclusive use.

I have just pulled out Webster's New Twentieth Century Dictionary of the English Language, Unabridged, Second Edition, Volume I, A through Microspectroscope. It gives 15 different meanings for the noun "Man":

a human being; a person, whether male or female.
the human race; mankind: used without the or a.

...
"Lion", however has only 5 different meanings. The first is the animal, Panthera leo; the second is a person of great courage, etc. There appears to be no usage of "lion" to mean "lionkind". (Maybe if lions had a language they would have 15 definitions of "lion"? Perhaps this is the essence of your question: I conjecture that all human languages treat humans differently from lions, horses, and tardigrades.)
@Loviii, I see from your profile that you are in Moscow, so you must have access to a great public library. Can you find a copy of the 12 volume Oxford English Dictionary ("Big Oxford")?

I don't know what you mean by "a great public library". I've found a torrent file for "Oxford English Dictionary 4.0", if need be.

@Loviii I meant somewhere like this. If you can download Big Oxford you will have a great reference. You might enjoy reading about William Chester Minor, one of the people who contributed to the first edition of the dictionary.

I couldn't find on that site where I can download it. I think it's easier to find it on torrent-sites.

@Loviii No. I expect that they would have a physical copy of the book, all 20 volumes. The Oxford doesn't just give you the meanings of the word: it also has quotations that support each meaning.

Like they have a book, I order it, they make a physical copy of the book I ordered, I go there and take the copy? If so, I think everyone can do it: the copy will be sent by post service.

Rather ironically, I found the following in the book I gave the link above: In OE. a few examples occur with the definite article. The Eng. use of the word as a quasi-proper name, without article, differs from the practice of most of the modern European langs. (cf. F. l'homme, G. der mensch), and from the usage of Eng. itself with regard to other generic names of animals: cf. ‘the anatomical structure of man and that of the lion’.

@Loviii "Like they have a book...". No. My local Library has a reference copy: i.e. it cannot be borrowed, but anyone can walk in and read it. Normally I would look something up in one of the dictionaries in my house, but, if necessary, I'd walk around to the public library (12 minutes). Moscow is a bit bigger than my town, but I hear you have a good Metro.

Leaving out the article before "man" is just for style and flavor. It's a personal choice. 2 and 3 are correct. 2 has a slightly different meaning, though.
"Man cannot live by bread alone."
"A man cannot live by bread alone."
These refer to all humans. Not one specific human, not specifically the male sex or the female sex. Humans, in general.
"The man cannot live by bread alone" (2)
This makes the sentence sound like you are referring to one specific human, who is male. It is similar to saying "My boyfriend, Steve, cannot live by bread alone."
"Men cannot live by bread alone." (3)
This refer to all humans again. Humans, in general. Does this refer to specifically the male sex or the female sex? The answer depends on the personal opinion of who you ask. Personally, I think this sounds like specifically the male sex. But other people probably think this doesn't.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The explanation may not be logical, but poetic. As a proverb it sounds more powerful through its triple-iambic metre.
